# Can table names be substitued with '?'

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a sqlite query:

```
rawQuery("select * from ? where ?=?", new String[] {
                DBTABLE_PROFILE, KEY_PROFILE_ID, Integer.toString(profileID) });
```

But Android gives me

```
E/AndroidRuntime(7323): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException:   
near "?": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: select * from ? where ?=?
```

I tested which ? was causing problems and it turned out to be the first one. If I change it to

```
"select * from profile where ?=?"
```

it doesn't FC.

SO, can table names be substitued with '?'?

[EDIT]:

There is a ***work-around*** to achieve rawQuery-like functionality without the limitations. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The only parameters that you should be substituted with `?` are the query variables, not table names and not column names.

The correct query is:

```
rawQuery("select * from " + DBTABLE_PROFILE + " where " + KEY_PROFILE_ID + "=?",
            new String[] { Integer.toString(profileID) });
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I did not know such limitations were imposed in sqlite statements.

Answer (score 0):

if you've tested it, then you have the answer.

I'm not sure, but I expect it is because *rawQuery* isn't doing string-concatenation behind the scenes - it will be preparing a stored procedure or similar, and then escaping the values into the procedure object.  As such, it needs to know the table name to create the procedure, so can't use substitution for the table name.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Sam for the pointers, I find myself amazingly stupid for even using rawQuery(String, String[]) due to the number of limitations.

IMO the best way to achieve rawQuery-like functionlaity without the limitations is to use rawQuery(String) with String.format()

ex:

```
 rawQuery(String.format("select * from %s where %s=%d",
                DBTABLE_PROFILE, KEY_PROFILE_ID, profileID));
```